# How do I maintain state between a dispatch bot and skill bot?

Tags: botframework

I am using the virtual assistant template provided via Microsoft's `botframework-solutions` Github repository, and I am having trouble maintaining the active dialog between our main entry point -- a bot developed that implements the dispatch model to determine which skill to send the user's utterance for further handling -- and the individual skill processes the user's input.

I have our dispatch model bot listening to POSTs made to `localhost:3979/api/messages` using the `route` method in `mainDialog.ts` to determine the relevant skill to pass the users' utterance to, which takes that utterance and determines which dialog within the skill should be used to handle the users' utterance. When we begin a dialog that implements a multi-step waterfall dialog, the dispatch model bot is not keeping track of the dialog that is active within the skill bot, and therefore the skill bot doesn't know how to route the users' utterance to the already active dialog. When we are POSTing directly to the skill bot and foregoing the dispatch model bot, the skill bot is able to keep track of the active dialog, which leads me to believe that we aren't properly managing state between the dispatch bot and the skill bot.

I've noticed that bot the virtual assistant and skill templates we're using from the `botframework-solutions` templates instantiate a new instance of `AutoSaveStateMiddleWare` within their `defaultAdapter.ts`, so it appears that reading and writing of conversation and user state should already be automatically managed.

mainDialog.ts within the dispatch bot, which routes utterances to the appropriate skill

```js
protected async route(dc: DialogContext): Promise<void> {
        // Get cognitive models for locale
        const locale: string = i18next.language.substring(0, 2);
        const cognitiveModels: ICognitiveModelSet | undefined = this.services.cognitiveModelSets.get(locale);

        if (cognitiveModels === undefined) {
            throw new Error('There is no value in cognitiveModels');
        }
        // Check dispatch result
        const dispatchResult: RecognizerResult = await cognitiveModels.dispatchService.recognize(dc.context);
        const intent: string = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(dispatchResult);

        if (this.settings.skills === undefined) {
            throw new Error('There is no skills in settings value');
        }
        // Identify if the dispatch intent matches any Action within a Skill if so, we pass to the appropriate SkillDialog to hand-off
        const identifiedSkill: ISkillManifest | undefined = SkillRouter.isSkill(this.settings.skills, intent);
        if (identifiedSkill !== undefined) {
            // We have identified a skill so initialize the skill connection with the target skill
            await dc.beginDialog(identifiedSkill.id);

            // Pass the activity we have
            const result: DialogTurnResult = await dc.continueDialog();

            if (result.status === DialogTurnStatus.complete) {
                await this.complete(dc);
            }
        } else if (intent === 'l_NOVA_general') {
            // If dispatch result is general luis model
            const luisService: LuisRecognizerTelemetryClient | undefined = cognitiveModels.luisServices.get(this.luisServiceGeneral);
            if (luisService === undefined) {
                throw new Error('The specified LUIS Model could not be found in your Bot Services configuration.');
            } else {
                const result: RecognizerResult = await luisService.recognize(dc.context);
                if (result !== undefined) {
                    const generalIntent: string = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(result);

                    // switch on general intents
                    switch (generalIntent) {
                        case 'Escalate': {
                            // start escalate dialog
                            await dc.beginDialog(EscalateDialog.name);
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'None':
                        default: {
                            // No intent was identified, send confused message
                            await this.responder.replyWith(dc.context, MainResponses.responseIds.confused);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            // If dispatch intent does not map to configured models, send 'confused' response.
            await this.responder.replyWith(dc.context, MainResponses.responseIds.confused);
        }
    }
```

The following code from the skill bot's `dialogBot.ts` which listens to all `turn` events

```js
public async turn(turnContext: TurnContext, next: () => Promise<void>): Promise<any> {
        // Client notifying this bot took to long to respond (timed out)
        if (turnContext.activity.code === EndOfConversationCodes.BotTimedOut) {
            this.telemetryClient.trackTrace({
                message: `Timeout in ${ turnContext.activity.channelId } channel: Bot took too long to respond`,
                severityLevel: Severity.Information
            });

            return;
        }

        const dc: DialogContext = await this.dialogs.createContext(turnContext);

        if (dc.activeDialog !== undefined) {
            const result: DialogTurnResult = await dc.continueDialog();
        } else {
            await dc.beginDialog(this.rootDialogId);
        }

        await next();
    }
```

The `mainDialog.ts` within the skill bot that routes to the `claims_claimsStatus` waterfall dialog

```js
protected async route(dc: DialogContext): Promise<void> {
        // get current activity locale
        const locale: string = i18next.language.substring(0, 2);
        const localeConfig: Partial<ICognitiveModelSet> | undefined = this.services.cognitiveModelSets.get(locale);

        // Populate state from SkillContext slots as required
        await this.populateStateFromSkillContext(dc.context);
        if (localeConfig === undefined) {
            throw new Error('There is no cognitiveModels for the locale');
        }
        // Get skill LUIS model from configuration
        if (localeConfig.luisServices !== undefined) {

            const luisService: LuisRecognizerTelemetryClient | undefined = localeConfig.luisServices.get(this.solutionName);

            if (luisService === undefined) {
                throw new Error('The specified LUIS Model could not be found in your Bot Services configuration.');
            } else {
                let turnResult: DialogTurnResult = Dialog.EndOfTurn;
                const result: RecognizerResult = await luisService.recognize(dc.context);
                const intent: string = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(result);

                switch (intent) {
                    case 'claims_claimStatus': {
                        turnResult = await dc.beginDialog(StatusDialog.name);
                        break;
                    }
.
.
.
```

Expected results: When using the dispatch bot to route to the skill bot, after beginning a waterfall dialog within the `claims_claimStatus` dialog, the `dialogContext.activeDialog` should be `statusDialog` for further steps of the waterfall dialog

Actual results: When using the dispatch bot to route to the skill bot, after beginning a waterfall dialog within the `claims_claimStatus` dialog, the `dialogContext.activeDialog` should is `undefined` for further steps of the waterfall dialog

Comment: Do you get any sort of response from the skill bot when you initiate a dialog via the main (dispatch) bot?